# .net core 2.2 Ws-Federation keeps redirecting during logining

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, ws-federation

I'm building a web application with WsFederation Authentication in **.net core 2.2**. The application is quite simple and the target is just pass the authentication and drop out some strings. The strange part is that when I access the page it redirect me to login page and keep login and login..., and not able to access the page. The **wctx** part of url changes every seconds. Please help me to figure the root cause, thanks.

https://login.microsoftonline.com/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47/wsfed?wtrealm=api%3A%2F%2F62287581-857a-4631-8397-9f1fe62a614d&wa=wsignin1.0&wreply=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8169&wctx= **CfDJ8Jgh4I_bsxBAiaSMihZSDOW7meA5qm5eqIxCJeyY0wjDxc4rHKtGLUI-FJoXNj4jjhu9NNozNM18Ga5x7rDxucjeLQqTLhlRzI2z9fgJbrSSHt1Svtvi-nj0rsHet4Zof13i_q36BKkJMwb3SxXaC30Rtuxy28gfwvybTs3etQoGxzlOjpGdpi2cThcsZQchKjFa44SIhrCU3zg5vFCLdleUQfCZo65vv13-lbQ2_GHF**

Here is my startup.cs

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
                {
                    sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddWsFederation(options =>
                {
                    options.Wreply = "https://localhost:8169";
                    options.Wtrealm = "api://62287581-857a-4631-8397-9f1fe62a614d";
                    options.MetadataAddress = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml";
                })
                .AddCookie();
            
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
```

And here is that simple page.

```
[Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        
        public string Index()
        {
            return $"Home. User:{HttpContext.User.Identity.Name}";
        }
        
        public string Welcome()
        {
            return $"Welcome. User:{HttpContext.User.Identity.Name}";
        }
    }
```

And here are the redirect urls in Azure application authentication settings.

https://localhost:8169/Home/Welcome

https://localhost:8169

https://localhost:8169/signin-wsfed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution.
Just add below codes and the issue is fixed.

```
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });
```